# On hovering of parent Element my child class css is not changing

Tags: html, css, hover

Here is my code in which on hover of a li tag the anchor tag color does not change. I have a list of products and on hover the background of the li should change and it does, but the problem is with the anchor tags text color, which does not change.

```css
.product-menu-container ul {
  padding: 10px;
}

.product-menu-container ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 11px 0px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
  background-color: #fbe3ef;
  /* border: 0.5px solid #fdadd9; */
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.product-menu-container ul li:hover {
  background-color: #de5499;
}

.product-menu-container ul li a {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #343434;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.product-menu-container ul li:hover .product-menu-container ul li a {
  color: #fff;
}

.product-menu-container h4 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  background: rgb(2, 103, 124);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(2, 103, 124, 1) 20%, rgba(38, 65, 67, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(2, 103, 124, 1) 20%, rgba(38, 65, 67, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(2, 103, 124, 1) 20%, rgba(38, 65, 67, 1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="product-menu-container">
  <h4>Our Products</h4>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">StudentCares</a></li>
    <li><a href="">StudentCares ID</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Graduex</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Sensify</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Hardware Product</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Gate & Barriers</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Mumbai Madiga Matrimony</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Electronic ID Card</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Smart Class Room</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `.product-menu-container ul li:hover .product-menu-container ul li a`- that selector makes little sense, for the given HTML. You do not have another level of `.product-menu-container ul li ` _inside_ your list items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.product-menu-container ul li:hover .product-menu-container ul li a` will not as a selector in CSS,  because you're trying to access this structure:

```
.product-menu-container
    ul
        li:hover
            .product-menu-container
                ul
                    li
                        a
```

Changing the selector to `.product-menu-container ul li:hover a` will work.

```css
.product-menu-container ul {
  padding: 10px;
}

.product-menu-container ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 11px 0px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
  background-color: #fbe3ef;
  /* border: 0.5px solid #fdadd9; */
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.product-menu-container ul li:hover {
  background-color: #de5499;
}

.product-menu-container ul li a {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #343434;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.product-menu-container ul li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}

.product-menu-container h4 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  background: rgb(2, 103, 124);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(2, 103, 124, 1) 20%, rgba(38, 65, 67, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(2, 103, 124, 1) 20%, rgba(38, 65, 67, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(2, 103, 124, 1) 20%, rgba(38, 65, 67, 1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="product-menu-container">
  <h4>Our Products</h4>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">StudentCares</a></li>
    <li><a href="">StudentCares ID</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Graduex</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Sensify</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Hardware Product</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Gate & Barriers</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Mumbai Madiga Matrimony</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Electronic ID Card</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Smart Class Room</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: hi Douwe thanks for answer I want to ask one thing if I use 'a' directly will it effects all a or only .product-menu-container anchor tags

Comment: @sumitdubey It will only affect the `.product-menu-container` anchor tags. Look at it like a sort of path finding way; with CSS you tell the browser which route to take to the last element.

Comment: hi Douwe Hann thank you so much for your valuable reply